# Drawables resources management in android

Tags: android, memory-management, drawable

I have one question. I made quick search on the site, but don't found answer.
We develop application that running android 2.2 and higher. For views customization we use many drawables, that used in such way:

```
<LinearLayout ...
    android:background="@drawable/some_drawable"/>
```

We use maps too and manipulate with many data in the memory, and our app got a heavy. On top devices, it work's great,but on other we got OutOfMemory exception after some minutes of using our application. It's look as we have memory leaks. 
I'm trying reduce the memory usage of our app. question, do we need manualy cleaning resources on destroing our activities: removes drawables for view, or system made it for us?

Comment: if you use a lot of bitmaps/drawables of high-res that will be scaled this will consume a lot of memory. are this issues in a specific activity? maybe where you present a listview with a lot of bitmaps in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this issue in my app as well.  `OutOfMemoryError` would be thrown if a lot of bitmaps were used in an activity, with scaling and/or other bitmap manipulation.  What I have done is added the following code to my activity, which seems to make the problem appearing less often (it didn't solve it for good) and the app now runs with no errors on a reasonably low-end handset.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    // explicitly release media player
    if(viewObjectInfo != null)
        viewObjectInfo.releaseMediaPlayer();
    //explicitly release all drawables and call GC
    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.main));
    System.gc();
}

/**
 * Unbinds all drawables in a given view (and its child tree).
 * 
 * @param findViewById     Root view of the tree to unbind
 */
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        try
        {
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
        catch(UnsupportedOperationException ignore)
        {
            //if can't remove all view (e.g. adapter view) - no problem 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.main));` is supposed to be `unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.layout.main));`?

Comment: What if I wanted to unbind all the images from the layout to free up resources until the layout is called again?

Comment: @SiKni8 To your first comment, I had it with `R.id.main` - you're getting the view, not the layout - although the layout may also work.  To your second one, don't unbind everything - just check what type of view it is.

Comment: I am having an issue with my app that you may be able to assist me I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473527/app-fc-on-reusing-drawable-resource

Comment: it is a bad practice to call System.gc(); It doesn't guarantee anything

Comment: @al_mukthar It may or may not be a bad practice, however it does guarantee to start the garbage collection process.